# Store to a powershell array, the value for each json key (with given name) regardless of json structure

Tags: json, powershell

Given a json file with any content/structure, where there are plenty of keys called "bob", how can I retrieve to an array, the values relating to all key instances called bob?

Eg:

```
Build list of all found keys called 'bob'
For each key
   obtain the corresponding value
   store it in array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Sample JSON input with "bob" properties at various levels of the object graph.
$json = @'
  {
    "bob": "carol",
    "foo": [
        {
          "bob": "ted"
        },
        {
          "bar": {
            "bob": "alice"
          }
        }
    ]
  }
'@

# Collect all "bob" property values in an array.
[array] $bobValues = 
  $json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    # Helper script block that walks the object graph and outputs
    # every "bob" property value.
    $sb = {
      foreach ($el in $args[0]) { # iterate over elements (if an array)
        foreach ($prop in $el.psobject.Properties) { # iterate over properties
          if ($prop.Name -eq 'bob') { $prop.Value } # output the value
          else { & $sb $prop.Value } # recurse
        }
      }
    }
    # Call the script block with the input object.
    & $sb $_
  }

# Print the array.
$bobValues
```

The above yields:

```
carol
ted
alice
```